# Java unknown cause for infinite loop

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have a code result that I cannot explain in Java 11 code that sends an email.

I am using the javax mail package:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

Here is the code:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

int nMaxTries = 5;
int nTries = 0;
boolean success = false;

while (!success || nTries >= nMaxTries) {
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        //set message headers
        msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
        msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
        msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, from));
        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setContent(body, "text/html");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));

        System.out.println("Message is ready");
        Transport.send(msg);

        System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
        success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        nTries++;
    }
}
```

I noticed that sometimes the email would fail, hence the retry. This runs using a cron process that pipes output to the logs. This has been working fine for several weeks. This morning, I received nearly 400,000 emails. I see this over and over in the logs:

```
Message is ready
EMail Sent Successfully!!
Message is ready
EMail Sent Successfully!!
Message is ready
EMail Sent Successfully!!
Message is ready
EMail Sent Successfully!!
Message is ready
```

This is a single threaded process. Looking at this I realize I can increment the counter in the loop vs just the catch statement so these infinite loops will stop. Can anyone explain the logic as far as how the while loop would fail to complete?

Thanks!

Comment: `&& nTries < nMaxTries`

Comment: it means `!success || nTries >= nMaxTries` is never satisfied. w can see that success is set to true, so there is a problem with `|| nTries >= nMaxTries`

Comment: This would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was stated, use

```
!success && nTries < nMaxTries
```

But forget about testing the success boolean and just break out of the loop when the email is sent.

```
while (nTries < nMaxTries) {
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        //set message headers
        msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
        msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
        msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, from));
        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setContent(body, "text/html");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));

        System.out.println("Message is ready");
        Transport.send(msg);

        System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
        success = true;    // keep for final status
        break;             // terminate the loop here.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        nTries++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, is the `Date()` class required here?  No imports were noticed, but `java.util.Date` is outdated and using classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package is recommended unless backward compatibility is required.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your while loop.

You have two conditions.

The first one being "continue while success is "false" "
And the second being "continue while nTries is equal or supperior to nMaxTries"

Now, if either the first or second second is a correct ( you used ||), the code inside your while instruction will be executed.

What I suspect is that the email failed to be sent 5 times in a unknow period of time (therefore incrementing the variable nTries to 5) and leading to the loop since the second condition is always true. (nTries >= nMaxTries).

In order to correct the issue, you want to do the following test :

```
!success && nTries < nMaxTries
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is wrong. It should be like this:

```
while (!success && nTries < nMaxTries)
```

Otherwise both `nTries` and `nMaxTries` start at 0 and the `>=` condition is always true no matter how many times you increment `nTries` and if the mail is sent correctly the `||` operator will still have in account the comparison between `nTries` and `nMaxTries` being true even though `!success` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a scenario, where for first 5 times, the send message failed (exception occurred), so your variable `nTries` is now equal to `nMaxTries` and now you have successfully sent the message, so `success=true`, but you have used OR condition, so it will check for second condition `nTries >= nMaxTries` which is true. So over all expression `!success || nTries >= nMaxTries` becomes true. Since this condition never changes, while loop is now stuck and has become infinite loop.